# sum all input elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, sum, input

Trying to figure out how to write a jquery formula that will sum all input fields that begin with "pull" on keyup...  I'm trying the code below, but nothing happens... No errors, and no updates either.... (the html is at the very bottom)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* sums pull total input fields */
    $("input[name^='pull']").bind("keyup", "calcPullTotal");
    calcPullTotal();
});


function calcPullTotal() {
    $("[id=totalpull]").calc(
        "pullnum + 0", { pullnum: $("input[name^=pull]") },
        function (s){
            return s.toFixed(0);
        },
        function ($this) {
            var sum = $this.sum();
                $("#totalpull").text(
                sum.toFixed(0)
            );
        }
    );  
}
<table id="convert">
<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="pull0" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="pull1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="pull2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="pull3" /></td></tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot><tr><td><input type="text" id="totalpull" name="totalpull" value="" /></td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This is more or less duplicate of the: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417553/jquery-calculate-sum-of-values-in-all-text-fields/2417591

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("input[name^='pull']").bind("keyup", calcPullTotal);
calcPullTotal();
```

You were passing the string "calcPullTotal" as the second argument to [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), which expects a `function`.

Comment: No, that didn't work either...  That's how I had it at first, but still nothing...

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't intend for me to take out of document.ready?

Comment: That didn't work.  It occurred to me that maybe because the input elements are within a table cell, I'd have to do something different?  I did try table > tbody > tr > td > input["name^=pull"], but didn't seem to have an effect... In any event, I updated the original post...