# How to sum all the column wise values of html table and display the sum in particular column's footer

Tags: php, jquery, html

My html table goes like below, In the footer of my table i want to add the "Total" and sum of all the values at the footer of particular "quarters"

```
"quarter1"  "quarter2" "quarter3" "quarter4"
 250000      115000         
             175000      600000     275000
 300000      150000      750000 
 650000                              450000 
 850000      290000      145000
```

my view code is like below
How to overcome my issue, please suggest me. Any helps are appreciated,
Thank you

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="referListTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>SI.No</th>
                              <th>Jan-Mar</th>
                              <th>Apr-Jun</th>
                              <th>Jul-Sep</th>
                              <th>Oct-Dec</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php 
                            $i=1;
                            foreach($dashboardDetails as $llist){
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                              <td align="right">$llist['previous']; ?></td>
                              <td align="right">$llist['quarter1'];?></td>
                              <td align="right">$llist['quarter2'];?></td>
                              <td align="right">$llist['quarter3'];?></td>
                              <td align="right">$llist['quarter4'];?></td>


                              </tr>
                            <?php 
                                $i++;
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Total</th>

                                <td id="total" ></td>
                                <td id="total" ></td>
                                <td id="total" ></td>
                                <td id="total" ></td>
                                <td id="total" ></td>

                            </tr>
                         </tfoot>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculating column and row sum in html table using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322113/how-to-calculating-column-and-row-sum-in-html-table-using-jquery)

Comment: what have you tried so far ? if data is coming from php loop, you can sum up while fetching through results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum all input elements in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418594/sum-all-input-elements-in-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum all values for table column based on class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293492/sum-all-values-for-table-column-based-on-class)

Comment: gone through some of those posts but didn't solve my problem. that is why i did post the question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var sums = []
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i, x) {
    if ($(x).html().length) {
      var tdValue = parseInt($(x).html());
      tdValue = (tdValue + parseInt(sums[i] == undefined ? 0 : sums[i]))
      sums[i] = tdValue
    }
  })
})
$.each(sums,function(i,x) {
  $("tfoot tr").append("<td>"+x+"</td>")
})
```

Note this is created before we had your html code in the question, but it should be able to give you an idea how to make it work with your own html code

```js
var sums = []
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i, x) {
    if ($(x).html().length) {
      var tdValue = parseInt($(x).html());
      tdValue = (tdValue + parseInt(sums[i] == undefined ? 0 : sums[i]))
      sums[i] = tdValue
    }
  })
})
$.each(sums,function(i,x) {
  $("tfoot tr").append("<td>"+x+"</td>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>quarter1</td>
      <td>quarter2</td>
      <td>quarter3</td>
      <td>quarter4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>250000</td>
      <td>115000</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>175000</td>
      <td>600000</td>
      <td>275000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>300000</td>
      <td>150000</td>
      <td>750000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>650000</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>450000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>850000</td>
      <td>290000</td>
      <td>145000</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  
</table>
```

Comment: It might be easy if the values are hard coded, but my case is different i am getting those values from my model query and looping those here. How to do the sum in this case?

Comment: I created the jquery from your example, take a copy of the html table after it has been generated and insert it into your question, else it hard to tell you what to do

Comment: thank you  @Carsten Løvbo Andersen, Sum is calculating just need to make some allignments

Comment: One more issue @Carsten Løvbo Andersen,  When i have some valid values then it is giving sum and displaying in the footer but along with that i have some columns which contains strings like name,email etc, in that case it is displaying as Undefined/NaN where i need to display empty or null. pleas help me out to do this