# How to calculate the total value of input boxes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of input boxes, now I need to calculate the total of all values entered in input boxes with the following naming convention pre[0],pre[1],pre[2] etc.

Is this possible with Jquery and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery calculate sum of values in all text fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417553/jquery-calculate-sum-of-values-in-all-text-fields)

Comment: @Reigel The problem is that they aren't *exact* duplicate. That one needs it to be triggered on the `blur` event, while this one requires that selector. You **can** conceivably merge them, but keep doing this to subtlety different questions and we'll end up with the jQuery documentation page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
var sum = 0;

$('input[name^="pre"]').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

`^=` is the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Ah, yours is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
var sum = 0;

find("input[name*='pre']").each(function(index) {

sum = sum + this.val();

 })
```

Comment: it's `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Comment: `this.value` is better because it does not create an additional jQuery object.