# Update value in textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three textboxes, when I modify either textbox A or Textbox B Textbox C should change to A*B  e.g. If A is 3 and B is 4 C is 12... if i change B to 5 C should automatically change to 15.   js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lazyboy4ever/mfyh2/

Comment: Your code is a mess, cleanup it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `.change()` event handler to `input`s `A` and `B`, convert their `value` to a number using `parseFloat()`, multiply them, and assign the result to `C`:

```
$("[name='qty'],[name='b']").change(function () {
   var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
       qty = $tr.find("[name='qty']").val(),
       b = $tr.find("[name='b']").val();

   var c = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(b); 
   $tr.find("[name='c']").val(c);
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TRvV8/)**.

Answer (score 2):

****I'll say, please search it but I'm afraid you'll ask "where?". So, please Google it before asking.****

**Change this solution to multiply :** [How to calculate the total value of input boxes using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699042/how-to-calculate-the-total-value-of-input-boxes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that might work for your case:

HTML:

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="txt2" type="text" /><br />
<input id="txt3" type="text" /><br />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('blur', '#txt1', function(){
        var one = $('#txt1').val();
        var two = $('#txt2').val();
        var three = $('#txt3').val();
        $('#txt3').val(one * two);        
    });     

        $(document).on('blur', '#txt2', function(){
        var one = $('#txt1').val();
        var two = $('#txt2').val();
        var three = $('#txt3').val();
        $('#txt3').val(one * two);        
    });       

});
```

[Example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMhSm/)