# Sum using jQuery each function without global variable

Tags: jquery, each

I want to add some HTML elements that have the same class name.

So, the code will be like this with jQuery.

```
$(".force").each(function (){
    a += parseInt( $(this).html());
});
$("#total_forces").html(a);
```

In this code, the variable has to be global.

Is there any other elegant way to sum every `.force` value and get the sum out of the `each` function without global variable?

Comment: Is there a problem with the method you're showing us?

Comment: @Surreal Read, he doesn't want to use a global variable.

Comment: He states that `a` is a global, but I'm hoping that he will clarify if that's the problem, or it's a matter of efficiency, incorrect result, etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to introduce a global variable, you could use something like this:

```
$("#total_forces").html(function() {
    var a = 0;
    $(".force").each(function() {
        a += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
    return a;
});
```

Comment: Nice. Actually `.html()` also accepts a function so no need to wrap in `( ... )()`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Much better! Also, now I have 4 spare parentheses I can use elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to keep *balance* on those suckers (Ba-dum tisssss)

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, if you're going to be needing this same functionality frequently, I'd probably just make a plugin.

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/tzw4mkL2/

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.sumHTML = function() {
       var sum = 0;
        this.each(function() {
           var num = parseInt( $(this).html(), 10 );
           sum += (num || 0);
        });
       return sum; 
    };
})( jQuery );
```

...which would be used like this:

```
$('#total_forces').html( $('.force').sumHTML() );
```

---

**EDIT:** Changed to guard agains `NaN` as noted by [@Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas). Also ensured base-10 in the `parseInt()` and fixed a closing `}` that was missing.

Comment: It may make sense to guard against NaN.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Why does `a` have to be global? It doesn't **have** to be global.

```
function aFunc() {
    var a = 0;

    $(".force").each(function (){
        a += parseInt( $(this).html());
    });

    return a;
}

$("#total_forces").html(aFunc());
```

Which, can be simplified to:

```
$("#total_forces").html(function() {
    var a = 0;

    $(".force").each(function (){
        a += parseInt( $(this).html());
    });

    return a;
});
```

Here `a` is local to `aFunc`, and is just one of millions of examples of it not being in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

Don't want a global?

```
(function() {
    var a = 0;
    $('.force').each(function (){
        a += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $('#total_forces').text(a);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(".force").length, it returns the number of elements in the jQuery object.

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Comment: I *think* @Raphappa wants the sum of the values **in** the .force elements.