# jquery loop over input value and get sum

Tags: jquery

I have input sliders (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahrichie/R7Hd4/)) that on change i'd like to loop through their values and get a total.

I wrote the code I thought would do this, but i failed, see the fiddle and thank you so much in advance!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahrichie/R7Hd4/)

```
Percentage Sliders<br><br>
<input type="tex" class="slida" type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-step="25" data-slider-snap="true" data-slider-theme="volume" >
<br><br>

<input type="tex" class="slida" type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="0,100" data-slider-step="25" data-slider-snap="true" data-slider-theme="volume" > 


$(".slida").bind("slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  console.log("Changed Value: ", data.value);
  $(this).each(function() {
    total = 0;
    $(this).each(function() {
        total += parseInt( $(this).val() );    
    });     
  });  
  console.log("TOTAL: ", total)

});
// end
```

Comment: You overwrite your total inside your each every single time, you need to specify your total outside the scope of the event binding. If you're looking to keep totals independently for the 2 sliders, that will require a little extra brain power.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum using jQuery each function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377410/sum-using-jquery-each-function)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$(this)` you iterate over is only the element that is changed, therefore `$.each()` will not serve any purpose under that context...however

```
var total = 0;
$('.slida').each(function(){
   total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Would definitely fit the mold, as you access the value of all the sliders, instead of just the one that you're firing the event on.

[As usual, here's your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMbzm/)

Comment: Fast, concise, and clean. Thank you so much!

Comment: if forget to parseInt