# Add number from divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, addition

I have these divs.

```
<div class="prices">11.99</div>
<div class="prices">1.99</div>
<div id="price">99</div>
```

How can I add all the numbers from the divs?

The final result must be 11.99+1.99+99=112.98

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean add? Where?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417553/jquery-calculate-sum-of-values-in-all-text-fields possible duplicate

Comment: I didn't knew how to start it. I knew that there must be some kind of a loop but didn't knew how to do it. And why all this hate? Geez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```js
var controls = $("div");
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
  var ct = parseFloat($(controls[i]).text());
  sum += ct;
}
alert(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prices">11.99</div>
<div class="prices">1.99</div>
<div id="price">99</div>
```

Comment: @semprom , cool ,you can also use `$("div").each` to make it work!

Comment: Plus at the end we can use sum.toFixed(2) to make the number 120.98 ( not 120.97999999999999 ).

Comment: Yes, but when i ran this in my browser, it directly gave me `120.98` .

Comment: It gives me the larger result. Strange. Never mind. I just wanted to tell if someone get the longer result to use toFixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to sum the values from divs with the class of prices or the id of price. You could do something like this:

```js
var p = 0;
$('.prices').each(function() {p += parseFloat($(this).text());})
$('#price').each(function() {p += parseFloat($(this).text());})    
$('#result').text(p);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prices">11.99</div>
<div class="prices">1.99</div>
<div id="price">99</div>
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is this:

```js
var sum = 0;
$("div").filter(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "prices" || $(this).attr("id") == "price") {
        return sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    }
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prices">11.99</div>
<div class="prices">1.99</div>
<div id="price">99</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code works...

**jQuery Code**

```
var price = 0;
$('div.prices, div#price').each(function(){ 
    price = price + parseFloat($(this).html());                 
});
alert(price)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6uLs92r7/