# Getting TextArea Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am submitting a form using JQuery. The form looks like below

```
<form class="ask-more-form">
<div class="product_info_2">
<textarea name="product_question" class="textbox" placeholder="Ask You Question Here"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1" id="product_id">
<a href="#" class="whiteButton submit" id="ask-more-submit-button">Ask Question</a>
</form>
```

And the JQuery to catch the form looks like this:

```
$('#ask-more').on('submit', '.ask-more-form', function() {
        var product_id = $(this).children('input[name=product_id]').val();
        var product_question = $(this).children('textarea[name="product_question"]').text();

alert(product_question);
//submitQuestion(product_id, product_question);

                });
```

The product_id is always read but the product question is is always null. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.children` [only goes one level down](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Use `.find` instead:

```
$('#ask-more').on('submit', '.ask-more-form', function () {
    var product_id = $(this).children('input[name=product_id]').val();
    var product_question = $(this).find('textarea[name="product_question"]').text();
    alert(product_question);
    //submitQuestion(product_id, product_question);
});
```

Comment: Is a combination of using val() and find

Comment: Personally, I would use `.val()`, but `.text()` will work for a `textarea`. See http://jsfiddle.net/kfD7b/ for a demo.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `text()` on a `<textarea>` when you should be using `val()`

```
var product_question = $(this).children('textarea[name="product_question"]').val();
```

This is true for other input element types like `<select>` and `<input>`

Comment: Should be noted that all elements designed for input, such as `input`, `textarea`, and `select` should be accessed using `val()`.  This is one of the things that makes jQuery awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`Use .val() instead of .text()`. It will do the trick

Comment: Maybe explain the difference between `.val()` and `.text()` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/807908/1183294).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `children` or `find`.  Since you already have the `id` of the form you can use that for your base and just use a standard jquery selector like so:

```
var product_question = $('textarea[name="product_question"]', this).val();
```

by adding a seocnd argument you are telling jquery to use only `this` as the DOM tree.