# Passing a variable into an alert

Tags: jquery

When the correct string, `foo`, is entered into `.guess` I am trying to pull the value from `.clicks` and pass it into an alert. When I load the page with my current code (below) the alert reads `Correct! You guessed it in  clicks.`. Why is the `clicks` variable not being passed?

Thanks

jQuery:

```
$('.guess').keyup(function() { 
    if ($('.guess').val() == "foo") {
        var clicks = $('.clicks').val();
        alert('Correct! You guessed it in ' + clicks + ' clicks.');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bar">
    <h2 class="clicks">0</h2>
    <input type="text" class="guess" />
</div>
```

Comment: val() is only used for input elements.  for all other elements, use html().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is primarily used for getting the value of form input elements.

I think you want to use `$(".clicks").text()`, OR
`$(".clicks").html()`,which will return `"0"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.guess').keyup(function() { 
    if ($('.guess').val() == "foo") {
        var clicks = $('.clicks').text(); // .text() instead of .val()
        alert('Correct! You guessed it in ' + clicks + ' clicks.');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.guess').keyup(function() { 
    if ($.trim( this.value ) == "foo") {
        var clicks = $('.clicks').text();
        alert('Correct! You guessed it in ' + clicks + ' clicks.');
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** click here :) http://jsfiddle.net/QSrWs/

please use api: `.text()`

This will help you to understand the difference: [Difference between val() and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-functions-val-and-text)

> Val() works on input elements (or any element with a value attribute?)
>   and text() will not work on input elements. Val() gets the value of
>   the input element -- regardless of type. Text() gets the innerText
>   (not HTML) of all the matched elements:

Hope this helps,

**code**

```
$('.guess').keyup(function() { 
    if ($('.guess').val() == "foo") {
        var clicks = $('.clicks').text();//$('.clicks').val();
        alert('Correct! You guessed it in ' + clicks + ' clicks.');
        location.reload();
    }
});​
```