# 8 ist not "8" in a javascript comparison

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden field with value "8" and I return json data from my asp.net mvc controller where the templateId has a value of 8.

"8" is not 8. Thats fine but how can I compare then both values?

[image]

Comment: It equals to string with 3 chars `"8"`. Quote, digit 8, quote. "but how can I compare then both values" - at first you need to find where the quotes come from

Comment: do you compare a string with a number?

Comment: Couldn't it be that the output is just putting quotes around it to show that it is a string? I'm sorry but I do not recognize this dev environment on the screenshot, so I do not know.

Comment: With the values you show, there is no reason that should not evaluate to true.  Visual Studio does add the quotes around the output of text(), so thinking that "8" is the literal is a red herring.

Comment: @John Koerner: that's the only explanation why it returns false. Any *other* ideas?

Comment: @zerkms At this point I would want to see a working version.  I have verified in VS that if the literal were "8" it would show ""8""

Comment: Can you debug this in a browser to ensure what's going on? Either add `console.log('Template ID: ' + response.templateId + ' Textbox: ' + $('#TemplateId').text())` right above the if statement or set a breakpoint.

Comment: ok I have the error: I did $("#TemplateId").text() == 8 which is false, then I did $("#TemplateId").val() == 8 which is true. Sorry guys my failure. Can someone write that as solution? I stepped into this trap...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-functions-val-and-text

Comment: This is really crazy. The condition is now TRUE but the code inside the if clause is never hit ??? Thats weird!

Comment: Haha finally got it: instead of a direct compare I do this then my if clause is executed: var selectedTemplateId = $('#TemplateId').val();
if (response.templateId == selectedTemplateId) { // it works} Below I put all this in an answer/solution.

Comment: "instead of a direct compare" --- this shouldn't change anything. Stop thinking that programming is some Voodoo magic

Comment: voodo magic? I wrote the facts here how I have experienced it. javascript is voodoo because of browser inconsistences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
if( response.templateId == $('#TemplateId').val())
{
    // never hit here
}
```

I did this and it worked:

```
var selectedTemplateId = $('#TemplateId').val();
if (response.templateId == selectedTemplateId)
{
   // it works
}
```

I also did a general test: 8 is the same as "8":

```
if( 8 == "8")
{
    // always hit here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you can compare two variable with type check or without type check

eg

```
 8 == '8' //true /* dont check type*/
 8=== '8'   //false /* check type*/
```

You don't need type checking while comparing. so 
your code will work fine.

Since you saying that your code is not working. and value of $("#TemplateId").text()  is '8'( shown in console). only possible problem is response.templateId is not equals to 8.

Comment: @zerkms his question is : how can I compare then both values?. I gave options for comparison.

Comment: And `==` returns false for OP. So - how strict comparison would it change?

Comment: @zerkms  Sorry, I did not consider 'strict mode'.

Comment: but still - I don't see how this is helpful. Yes, `==` compares 2 operands, so?

Comment: I tested it in 'strict mode'. no difference in result.

Comment: Right. For op the `==` comparison returns `false`. Obviously `===` would return false as well. The question is - why's that.

Comment: "You don't need type checking while comparing. so your code will work fine." -- op doesn't have type checking and code doesn't work. And that's why I said 12 mins ago that this is not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `parseInt($('#TemplateId').text())`?

Comment: @zerkms Since response.templateId is an integer, it would cast the text from #TemplateId as an interger - allowing him to compare both values.

Comment: even if it's not an integer - you can compare them without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to the string returned from text().

Answer (score 1):

You can always parse "8" to an Integer with "parseInt(str, 10)"