# Showing data in an html area by another areas id and value

Tags: jquery

I am currently trying to get a value of another area via id to append in the `#delivery_prices` section.  What is the correct way to do this?

`#shipping_methods` is a dropdown
`#delivery_price` is a div

```
$('#delivery_price').html($('#shipping_methods').val());
```

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML, too.

Comment: Does the code you have not work? How does it fail?

Comment: Is your code in a document ready call? Are you getting any errors in the console? What you have seems fine, so a jsFiddle might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `val()` method for containers like span, div, td ...
Use `html()` or `text()` methods

```
$('#delivery_price').html($('#shipping_methods').html());
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/807908/2806497) to have a better explanation about difference between `val` and `text`.

Comment: How do you know what type of element shipping_methods is?

Comment: thanks,  but I have a dropdown with <option value="" so would I not need to use .val()?

Comment: @j08691 He talks about "area", i guess it is `div` or another container