# .val() or .text() to find value of input in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

Any idea what is best practice for getting the value out of a form input field (that is second in the markup after it's label)?

I have been able to get the rest of the values fine (SKUs and price) but quantity is tricky.

**JSFIDDLE to whole thing:** http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/7HXBQ/33/

Here is some jQuery that scopes the first tr of the table and then attempts to get into that row and pull out the quantity value:

```
var BSKfirstQTY = $(BSKfirstrow).find('td.quantity').text('input value');
```

But as you can see from the fiddle's result pane, it's spewing out `[object Object]`.

NOTE: Leaving the .text() empty results in the it picking up the word **Qty** in the fiddle result pane (which is the label, not the number).

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Comment: I sometimes prefer the jQuery/native hybrid: `$(BSKfirstrow).find('td.quantity')[0].value`

Comment: It's because you try to use .val() on your td instead of your input. instead of doing .find('quantity').val() just do .find('quantity input').val()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass an argument into `text()`, you are setting the content of `td.quantity` to that string, and JQuery will return the object for [chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/). If you call `text()` with no argument, you will get the text inside the element.

You should use `.val()` to retrieve the values of input/textarea/selects elements, like so:

```
var BSKfirstQTY = $(BSKfirstrow).find('td.quantity input').val();
```

For more info on val vs. text, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text).

Comment: beat me to the punch!!! :) I would probably use td.quantity > input, but that's just me.

Comment: Good point. For other people's reference, `td input` will select any `input` that's a descendent of `td`, where `td > input` will only select `input`s that are direct children of `td`.

Comment: I was so close! Thank you @ZachRattner, big help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Difference between val() and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text)
He says that .text() won't work on input elements.

```
.val()
```

http://api.jquery.com/val/

```
.text()
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

I think there's not really a "best practice" scenario, since they both do different things. It just seems like it's the same, but if you're working with a form you really want to use `.val()`. Otherwise `.text()` might suffice.