# Pull Current value from text box and put in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, textbox

i'm attempting to put a value from a text box into a variable

text box looks like so:

```
<input type="text" size="30" name="group1name" value="Group 1" id="g1n">
```

pulling looks like so:

```
var group1name = $('#g1n').attr('value');
```

it will pull "Group 1" but if i change the text box it still pulls "Group 1" how can i make it pull the CURRENT value of the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var group1name = $('#g1n').val()
```

simple.

Comment: @user1547167 you are welcome , please choose as correct answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`var group1name = $("#g1n").val();`

Comment: and no it is val() trust me.

Comment: You are correct, I tend to mix them up. Here is more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text