# I've problems to clear inputs text width jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well.... i've the next problem and i don't know for why....

I need clear some inputs, the value and text but the text in the input not clear.

My code:

```
$("#bloque-addDireccion").each(function(){
      var input = $(this).find("input[name$='Mia']");
      $(input).each(function(){
          $(this).text("");
          $(this).attr("value","");
      });              
});
```

I'm inspect the inputs and the value it's correct ("") but i've the older text always in the input.

What i'm do wrong?

Comment: try `$(this).val('');`

Answer (score 6):

The `.text(text)` method cannot be used on form inputs. To set the text value of input or textarea elements, use the `.val(value)` method.

please also check the [Difference between val() and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text/807908#807908)

try [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-value)

```
 $(this).val("");
```

Comment: you should've explained why like the other answer did.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned to change the value you need to do `$(this).val("");`.
Me being a beginner as well, my guess why .text() does not work is because as mentioned here: `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp`, `<input>` does not have a text attribute, therefore at this example, `$(this).text()` seems to point at nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well... My solution: I chage the value in other javascript using .value("xxxxx"); to change the value and I change this for

```
.attr("value","xxxx");
```

And, when I try to reset/change next time the value, i'm using

```
.attr("value","xxxx");
```

and it's works....If put .val("xxx"); isn't works!

Thanks for all responses! :D