# Loop through all cells in table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, cell

What would be the best way to achieve this using jQuery, I'm trying to change the text for each cell upon row click, but I can't access the cell text in the first place (`str` is empty):

```
$("tr").bind("click", function() {
    $cells = $(this).children();
    $cells.each(function(index, cell) {
        var str = $(cell).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: `var str = $(cell).text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `td` does not have a value. Use `.text()` instead:

```
$("tr").bind("click", function() {
    $cells = $(this).children();
    $cells.each(function(cell) {
        var str = cell.text();
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I know when to use val() and when to use text()?

Comment: Use `.val()` on input elements. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text