# Apply placeholder on all tags?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i dont want to apply placeholder on `<input>` tag. I want apply `div` and `p` tag or may be other. One solution for `div` is as below.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="test" placeholder="Start writing here..."></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #test:empty:after {
     content: attr(placeholder);
  }
```

Any other solution which work for both `p` and `div` tag??

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/d3975/5/

Comment: Indeed...placeholder is just an attribute...as suggested by @VitorinoFernandes just substitute a `data-attribute` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this jquery style of approach:

below script iterate through each div and sets the text of each div to the placeholder of particular div.

You could use any tag in place of div. 
If you want to "P" tag just replace $("div") with $("p").
One exception is you could use text for block elements and val for input elements.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text) you will find the difference between val and text

**HTML**

```
  <div id="test" placeholder="Start writing here..."></div>
  <div id="test1" placeholder="Start writing here...1"></div>
  <div id="test2" placeholder="Start writing here...2"></div>
```

**js**

```
$("div").each(function(index,value){
   $(this).text($(this).attr('placeholder'));
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/wigabivanica/1/edit)