# Showing Jquery Variable in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have used jQuery Datepicker successfully for some time to input two dates ("ArrivalDate" and "DepartureDate"). Now I am trying to adapt the present page to show the difference between the two. This should be revealed (jQuery slideDown) after the second date has been inputted.

My HTML is

```
<form action="tba.php" method="post" id="bookform" name="bookform">
    <table cellspacing="3px" width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
<b>Arrival Date: </b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="ArrivalDate" id="ArrivalDate" size="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
<b>Departure Date: </b>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="DepartureDate" id="DepartureDate" size="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="numnights" style="display:none">
        <table cellspacing="3px" width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" width="48.5%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>That's <span id="nights"></span> nights in total</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the jQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //jQuery UI datepicker
    $("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        minDate: 0,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onClose: function () {
            var DepDate = $('#DepartureDate');
            var limitDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            //add 1 day to Arrival Date
            limitDate.setDate(limitDate.getDate() + 1);
            DepDate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', limitDate);
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });

    $('#DepartureDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "d M yy",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });

    //Reveal number of nights
    $("#DepartureDate").on("change", function () {
        var arr_date = $("#ArrivalDate").datepicker('getDate');
        var dep_date = $("#DepartureDate").datepicker('getDate');
        var diff = Math.floor((dep_date.getTime() - arr_date.getTime()) / 86400000);
        $('#nights').val(diff);
        $("#numnights").hide().slideDown(1200);
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yfhxo6at/)**

The problem I have is that the span (id=nights) is always blank. I have tried substituting other elements:
input works
p doesn't work

How can I persuade it to display a piece of text saying "That's 5 nights in total"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#nights')` selects the `<span id="nights"></span>` element. Only form inputs have the `.val()` method. What you're looking for is `.text()` which is used for inserting text nodes into

```
$('#nights').text(diff);
```

Note that `.html()` would work as well

```
$('#nights').html(diff);
```

But, `.html()` causes the value to be rendered as HTML, which could be slightly slower simply because it has to be sent to the HTML parser but it won't be noticeable.

Comment: So simple. (Nearly as simple as me!) Tiny Giant gets the green tick because his answer is the most comprehensive, but all answers were valid. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.text()` for the span and not `.val()`:

```
$('#nights').text(diff);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yfhxo6at/1/)**

See [Difference between val() and text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text) for reference

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.html()` to add that text in.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
$(".element").text(jQuery element here);
```