# JQuery find by id returning an array

Tags: jquery

JQuery selector starting with `#` indicates an ID selection. There can always be only one element with the given ID. Somehow, JQuery was implemented to always return an array from the calls like `$("#elemID")`.

To change the value of an element now, I have to write like:

```
$("#elemID")[0].value = "something";
```

Is there a different method to do this without referring an array index like:

```
$.getElem("elemID").value = "something";
```

Comment: With jQuery, if it is a form element: `$('#elem').val('value');`. Else `$('#elem').text('value')`. See http://api.jquery.com/val/ and http://api.jquery.com/text/ respectively.

Comment: Generally it's bad practice to have more than one object with the same value in the ID tag.  After all, what good is an **identifier** if it doesn't uniquely identify a specific object?

Comment: Difference between `.val()` and `.text()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/807908/3648578

Comment: Thanks Kosmos!  It works.  But it always returns an array and sets the first objects value/text.  I am good using it because i need not put array format in the code.

Comment: *" There can always be only one element with the given ID"* - this is not true. There can be many such elements at a time in DOM. browser doesn't present you from doing so. It's just invalid markup. `invalid!=impossible`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery selectors always return an array, even if that array is only one actual HTML element.  Well, not really an array, it's a jQuery wrapper object, but it acts like an array.

If you want to set the value of an HTML object, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('#elem').val('value');
```