# getting input tags value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

i have this input tags

```
<div id="tag" >
<tags-input  v-model="tags" id="meta_keyword" ></tags-input>
</div>
```

when i insert word,it look like this:

[image]

i try this code this code to get this input value(words inserted),

```
var meta_keyword_it=$('#meta_keyword').val();
alert(meta_keyword_it);
```

but i dont work,it alert empty!!!

Comment: have you tried `.text()` - `.val()` is reserved for form inputs (not sure how that tag is rendered - does it get converted?)

Comment: good,.text() is the solution,thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do I use .val() vs .innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351609/when-do-i-use-val-vs-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `.text()/.html()` because  does not have value property

```js
var meta_keyword_it=$('#meta_keyword').text();
alert(meta_keyword_it);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag" >
<tags-input  v-model="tags" id="meta_keyword" >dfg</tags-input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
var meta_keyword_it=$('#meta_keyword').text();
alert(meta_keyword_it);
```

Just change `val()` by `text()`.

If it will not work then you need to inspect created tag with some input text.
I think now you are just showing empty input tag.

Comment: change val() by text() fix the problem,thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you should have to replace `val` to `text` .`val()` works on input elements (or any element with a value attribute?) and `.text()` will not work on input elements. `.val()` gets the value of the input element -- regardless of type. `.text()` gets the innerText (not HTML) of all the matched elements: [see more  at here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/difference-between-val-and-text)

```js
function check(){
var val = $("#meta_keyword").text();
console.log(val);
}
check();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tag" >
<tags-input  v-model="tags" id="meta_keyword" >Abcd , xyz </tags-input>
</div>
```

Comment: change val() by text() fix the problem,thank you for your help