# How to pass value in input tag?

Tags: javascript

normally, i am trying passing value in p,div and pre tag and values are show in above tag now i am passing country name in input tag. but value are not show in input tag. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get browser and ip address </title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="https://ipdata.co">ipdata.co</a> - IP geolocation API</h1>
<input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" value="">
<p id="country_name"></p>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<pre id="response"></pre>

<script> 

$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#city").html(response.country_name + ", " + response.region);
    $("#country_name").html(response.country_name);
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI `id` tags should be unique within an HTML page. You have two elements with the `id=country_name`. So the selector, `$('#country_name')` is going to match two elements on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set input value using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Which is not supported in jquery. You need to use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set input value. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41351706/6555572) is the explanation for the same.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Get browser and ip address </title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><a href="https://ipdata.co">ipdata.co</a> - IP geolocation API</h1>
<input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" value="">
<p id="country_name"></p>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="city"></div>
<pre id="response"></pre>

<script> 

$.get("https://api.ipdata.co?api-key=test", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#city").html(response.country_name + ", " + response.region);
    $("#country_name").val(response.country_name);
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one item can have a specific id. Try using classes if you want them to share something.
Since both the

and  have the same id it will not work
Note that you can getElement**S**ByClassName but you can only get**Element**ById with the class allowing multiple and ID only allowing for one

Answer (score 2):

input fields take `value` attribute. Try changing this line:
`$("#country_name").val(response.country_name);`

Also, like @Khaleb said, element IDs must be unique.