# Pushing Object into an Array failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a object `creationParams` declared outside of all my functions. The object will be manipulated throughout the functions. However, I'm having an issue in pushing an Object to `creationParams`'s Property with an `Array` datatype.

**Code**

```
var creationParams = {};
creationParams.Project = {};
creationParams.Project.Workplaces = [];

$(#foo).click(function() { //this is the function that runs before someid
   //input validations here...

   creationParams.Org = $('#SelectedOrg').val();
   creationParams.Token = '';
});

$('#someid').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('href', '#');

    function isWpExisting(o) {
        for (var cntr = 0; cntr < creationParams.Project.Workplaces; cntr++) {
            if (creationParams.Project.Workplaces[cntr].Name.toUpperCase() === o) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#wp-name').val() === '') {
        $('#wp-name').addClass("error-field").attr("data-original-title", "Please enter Workplace Name");
        $(this).attr('href', '#');
    }
    else if (isWpExisting($('#wp-name').val().toUpperCase()) === true && !$('#wp-wpcreate').attr('wp-edit')) {
        $('#wp-name').addClass("error-field").attr("data-original-title", "This Workplace is already existing");
        $(this).attr('href', '#');
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr('href', '#divWp-one');
        $('#wp-name').removeClass("error-field").removeAttr("data-original-title");
        var workPlace= {};
        workPlace.Name = $('#wp-name').val();
        workPlace.Description = $('#wp-description').val();

        if ($('#wp-wpcreate').attr('wp-edit')) {

            for (var t = 0; t < creationParams.Project.Workplaces.length; t++) {
                if (creationParams.Project.Workplaces[t].Name === $('#wp-wpcreate').attr('wp-edit')) {
                    creationParams.Project.Workplaces[t] = workPlace;
                    $('#wp-wpcreate').attr('wp-edit', '');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            creationParams.Project.Workplaces.push(workPlace);
        }
    }
});

//
  ...some more functions here
//
```

Im getting an error of **"Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"**. I just want my object to be pushed to the Array. I have tried making another array and pushing into it and it works.

**Update:** I tried `console.log(creationParams.Project.Workplaces);` and gave me `undefined`.

**Update 2:** I got it working by moving the complete initialization of the `creationParams.Project.Workplaces` in the `#foo` function. I wonder why though, what is the difference of initializing it in a different place?

**Questions**

1. Why is it behaving like this?
2. <s>How can I make it work?</s> Fixed (*see Update 2*)

Comment: post more code or an example snippet because it seems to work here

Comment: Your issue is not replicated in the code you've provided. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfzcn8eu/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/807908/5061290

Comment: Updated snippet, Thanks!

Comment: @AhmetZeybek yes, I am using input types. I can actually retrieve the values from the respective id's.

Comment: @Hexxed can you show console.log output of `creationParams.Project.Workplaces` in the else block where you're trying to push. also check type of`creationParams.Project.workPlaces`. i don't see any problem in code. may be somewhere you're manipulating workplaces and changing it to anything other than array

Comment: @CodeManiac Weirdly enough. I'm getting `undefined` for it. But why though?

Comment: This can be a silly answer but try. I can see a small mistake in `isWpExisting` function. it should change like this `cntr < creationParams.Project.Workplaces.length`;. and try to define you global object like this. `var  creationParams = { Project : { Workplaces : [] } }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help guys. I got it working (*see update 2*). But im wondering why.